# Datatable Select logic

Tags: vb.net, select, datatable

So I have a datatable named 'users' that looks like this.

```
UserName | Rank | Amount | OrderCount
jsmith   |  2   |  30    |    15
jdoe     |  2   |  30    |    0
japple   |  2   |  30    |    5
```

I'm trying to create a function that will go through and return the UserName with the lowest OrderCount. So far I have this below:

```
Function DetermineBestUser(ByVal usertable As DataTable) As String

    Dim bestchoice As DataRow()

    bestchoice = usertable.Select("Rank = 2", "OrderCount ASC")

    Return bestchoice(0)(0).ToString
End Function
```

I do see one problem already, my rank will be either 1 or 2. If the user's rank is 1, they should get returned even if a user with a rank 2 has a lower OrderCount. The orderCount should never be more than what is in the Amount column (already have a function to check for that).

So, in this example, I would like jdoe to be returned because she has the lowest OrderCount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
bestchoice = usertable.Select("", "Rank DESC, OrderCount ASC")
```